# How to change default admin settings in django-registration?

Tags: django

How to change default admin settings in django-registration https://github.com/nathanborror/django-registration/blob/master/registration/admin.py ? I need add to `list_display` first_name, last_name and email

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own admin class derived from ModelAdmin (or even RegistrationAdmin if you only need to modify a couple of things), and then call admin.site.unregister and then re-register it with your own class.